# Plugins and exporting an API between python scripts

Tags: python, api, import

I've got a python script, which should read a subdirectory and make all the scripts within it callable like this:

```
python mainscript.py subscript arguments
```

I've figured out most of the details but I'm having a lot of trouble deciding on how to export an API (object or selected functions) to `subscript`s that `mainscript` imports. The intention is for the `subscript`s to work as pluggable commands to `mainscript` (in other words, there is no need for them to work stand-alone).

Things I've tried, that I think would be elegant enough are (after `import subdirectory.subscript` in `mainscript`):

1. `import __main__`

   which works, but gives my subscript access to everything unconditionally and will likely be a source of horrible bugs if this is to be used by others.
2. `from __main__ import *`

   which doesn't work despite defining `__all__` to include the name `api` at the end of `mainscript` (I just get told that `name 'api' is not defined` when I try to reference the object I want).
3. `from __main__ import api`

   which tells me `cannot import name api`.

So I'm at a position where, I either do the haphazard `import __main__` which I don't like at all, or have to move the api to a different file, which I also dislike because it would break the intended structure of:

```
mainscript.py
  - subdirectory:
    - subscript:
      subscript.py
```

which, despite `__init__.py` files that have to be everywhere along the chain, is relatively simple to work with. An `api.py` somewhere would mean that, to maintain simplicity, I'd have to move `mainscript.py` and `api.py` into their own subdirectory and have a calling script where `mainscript.py` used to be (a python script, to keep things easily cross-platform, but that just adds *another* script to the chain). I want to keep everything simple and obvious, which is why I'd prefer to have the simple api *within* the master caller script.

**In summary: What is the recommended, if any, way to export an api object from a calling script to called scripts? Is this approach to exporting an api wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the API into a Python package and install it. Then it is out of your way, and the structure of the scripts' directories can remain as it is.

Comment: but that's exactly what I wanted to avoid: having to turn the API into a package. It turns out my ordering in the main file was backwards and I fixed it. I left the question open to see if there's a different standard approach to doing this but it seems there isn't (further searching didn't reveal anything). I'm unsure if I should delete the question - I'm accepting this answer just to close the issue, but I must state that it is the solution I wanted to avoid. Regardless, my original design seems to work now.